# imap_open Copy email to folder and then Delete the email

Tags: php

I am looping through emails using the PHP function `imap_open`

Once the loop on each email has finished, how can i move or copy it to a specific folder then delete it?

Here is my code:

```
//try to connect
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
//grab emails
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

//if emails are returned, cycle through each...
if($emails) {
    //begin output var
    $output = '';

    //put the newest emails on top
    rsort($emails);

    //for every email...
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    //run queries etc here
    }
}
```

At the moment I am just deleting the email using:

```
//delete the email
//this deletes the email
imap_delete($inbox,1);
//this bit really really deletes the email
imap_expunge($inbox);
```

Comment: Rather than copy and delete, just move: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php

Comment: i have tried to use imap_mail_move($inbox,$email_number,"test"); but its not moving the email. not errors or anything!

Comment: test is a folder that exists